# What if you have a careers CV but want to post a job as an employer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, jobs, cv, employers

Using OpenId makes it somewhat bothersome to have separate accounts for employers and resumes (since you have to remember which account is tied to which openId provider).

Also, I'm assuming an employer can post multiple jobs from the same account, but if not, then the multi-login thing becomes even more of a nightmare...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Careers terms, you're either a CV owner, or an employer -- you *cannot* be both.

At least not with the same OpenID.

Thus, if you really want to do this, you must use two different OpenIDs.

Comment: So I guess that means that any given employer can post multiple jobs with the same ID?

Comment: This is too bad. I am responsible for hiring in my company, but also somewhat looking. OpenID is a wonderful tool for 'single sign on', in fact that is what it was built for I think. Kind of a breach of philosophy here.

Comment: @Ralph - you should have your own "personal" OpenID that you use for your CV and set up a second "work" OpenID for the employer stuff. That way if you do leave the company, the OpenID you used for the employer stuff can stay with the company.

Comment: I agree with Graeme. You are more than the company you work for, thus, *your* OpenID should be yours personally.

Comment: Employers do not "post" jobs -- that's not how careers work. They search through the pool of CVs. I suggest reading the http://careers.stackoverflow.com/faq and http://careers.stackoverflow.com/about if you have not already.

Comment: @Graeme - True, if not self employed. Even then it would be better to do so, I guess. Still, if I would want to do both, there should be a possibility to do so.

Comment: @Jeff - you wonderfully explain that employers do not post, but search through the pool. There seems to be no reason at all that I as an owner of a CV should not be able to search the pool, if I want to and pay for it. Do I really have to log out and log in again?

Comment: I rethought the "work" OpenID. My company will not pay for careers. I just want to find great coworkers, adding to the toolbox my company uses. But then, changing jobs, I do not want to invest again, but take the account with me. It would take much to convince a Swiss company to use careers at this time, with no stats and all...

Comment: I agree with Ralph

Comment: +1 I also agree.  This seems like an oversight, and judging by the lack of any real reason for this behavior in Jeff's response, I'm guessing it's not a simple fix :)

Comment: it's 100% intentional. Ever notice how, when you have an open house for sale, many of the visitors aren't legitimate buyers but curious neighbors?

Comment: Fair enough - that makes sense.  But as long as you *are* offering some form of search results for free to employers, do you really think forcing people to register a separate OpenID is a high enough barrier to entry?  And do you think that the number of people exploiting this loophole will be as high as the number of developers who are both involved in the hiring process *and* want to have their CV listed here?  (Side note: is there a way to delete your CV and switch your existing account into "employer mode"?)

Answer (score 5):

This is caused by a bad design decision, or perhaps there are some technical reasons behind it. Someone though you cannot sensibly be in both roles at the same time or even in one role first and second role later, or it was somewhat easier to implement it this way.

Still, forcing someone to create two OpenIDs for one site is quite ironic considering OpenID is meant to provide unified login infrastructure.

Comment: I'm also in the camp that feels that having to create two OpenIDs is somehow abhorrent.