# Make The "You Can't Be Employer and Employee" Experience Better

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

I have now discovered that you can't be an employer and an employee. However, this wasn't at all clear from the website and I only discovered it after searching and finding [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30757/what-if-you-have-a-careers-cv-but-want-to-post-a-job-as-an-employer) about it.

Before discovering the limitation I recalled seeing links to the employer view on the home page, so I tried logging out and clicking the "We're Hiring" button on the unauthenticated user's home page. This took me through my OpenID login pages and dropped me back at my CV.

Would it not make sense to:

1. Add a "tab" to the Employee site that says "We're Hiring" but then explains to the user that to be an employer you need to log in with a different account (and perhaps provide links on that page to make the process quick and easy)
2. When someone logs in via the homepage's "We're Hiring" and is registered as an Employee give them a message telling them why they're seeing their CV again.

I'm totally cool with the limitation, but the user experience surrounding that limitation could be better. It shouldn't require a trip to meta.stackoverflow.com in order to find out that this limitation exists.

Comment: **Hear, hear!**

Answer (score 5):

Yay, two OpenIDs!

Isn't this the exact problem that OpenID was intended to solve, needing to create new accounts for every site you visit?  So now I have to make a new throwaway OpenID just so that I can search through resumes at this site.

It's not a hard problem to solve, either.  I have personally built 3 different sites where users can be from one or more conflicting user groups.  Various Marketplace sites have been doing this for 15 years now.  Why have this silly restriction at all?

Comment: I agree, and have +1 voted other questions that suggest this restriction be removed. However, in light of the fact that those questions generally get closed as "by design" I'd love to see the limitation explained and dealt with in the user experience.

Answer (score 5):

This has been working much better for a while now, we just forgot to update this answer.  If you see any bugs related to this, post them as a separate question.

**Edit** I should clarify that there is now nothing that prevents Job Seekers / Candidates from being Employers as well (or vice versa...)

Answer (score 4):

i am not totally cool with the situation.  I am a developer but I am also a decision maker in hiring new employees.  Why is that strange?

Comment: There are several questions here on meta that have asked for the ability to have a dual role on Careers. Those have generally been closed as "by design". Hence, I'm not asking for the design to be changed. Instead, for the design to be made clearer to users.